# Calculating Time difference when In and Out time is in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample data:

```
ID          StartTime                       IPStatus   
A           2019-12-23 11:28:24.190             1   
B           2019-12-23 11:28:24.190             1 
B           2019-12-23 11:28:35.593             1 
A           2019-12-23 11:28:35.593             1 
A           2019-12-23 11:28:51.830             1 
B           2019-12-23 11:28:51.830             1 
B           2019-12-23 11:29:03.140             0 
A           2019-12-23 11:29:03.140             0 
A           2019-12-23 11:30:03.140             0 
B           2019-12-23 11:30:03.140             0 
B           2019-12-23 11:35:03.140             0 
A           2019-12-23 11:35:03.140             0 
A           2019-12-23 11:40:03.140             1 
B           2019-12-23 11:40:03.140             1 
B           2019-12-24 11:40:03.140             1 
A           2019-12-24 11:40:03.140             1 
A           2019-12-25 11:40:03.140             0 
B           2019-12-25 11:40:03.140             0 
B           2020-01-25 11:40:03.140             0 
A           2020-01-25 11:40:03.140             0 
A           2021-01-25 11:40:03.140             1 
B           2021-01-25 11:40:03.140             1
```

I need to calculate for how many time ID A and B are In and Out in Days:Hours:Min:Seconds format.
Ipstatus 1 means IN and 0 Means out.

I have this code which calculates time difference in Days:Hours:Min:Seconds

```
Declare @start datetime = '2019-06-26 12:14:13',@End datetime = '2019-08-27 12:14:36'

 select convert(varchar(550),DateDiff(day, @start, @End)%3600)+'D : '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @start, @End)/3600/60)+'H : '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @start,     @End)%3600/60)+'M : '+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @start, @End)%60)) +'S'   as Duration
```

But It works when we have 2 separate columns. How to calculate the time difference in above mentioned scenario?? Please suggest

Expected Output:

```
 ID         Status      TotalTime
 A          1           10D : 10Hr : 15 min : 15 sec    
 A          0           10D : 10Hr : 15 min : 15 sec  
 B          1           10D : 10Hr : 15 min : 15 sec    
 B          0           10D : 10Hr : 15 min : 15 sec
```

NOTE: I just entered the random total.

A 1st Starttime   2019-12-23 11:28:24.190
A  2nd Strattime 2019-12-23 11:28:35.593
A  3rd Starttime  2019-12-23 11:28:51.830

11 + 16 = 16 sec for Ipstatus = 1 and so on

Comment: What results do you want?  And can you explain what you mean by:  "calculate for how mant time ID A and B are In and Out in Days:Hours:Min:Seconds format"?   That is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5040df/1)

```
SELECT ID,IPStatus,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartTime], EndTime)%3600))+ ' D :'
    +CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUM(DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime], EndTime)/3600/60))+ 'H: '
    +CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUM(DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime],     EndTime)%3600/60))+ 'M: '
    +CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUM(DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime], EndTime)%60))+ 'S'
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID,[IPStatus],[StartTime],LEAD([StartTime]) over (PARTITION BY ID,[IPStatus] ORDER BY [StartTime]) AS EndTime
    FROM Table1
)T
WHERE StartTime<>EndTime
    AND EndTime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID,IPStatus
```

Comment: Thank you !! Luv. but can you Also convert days in year as well because in my outoput it shows as 385 days so can you tell me how to convert it to 1 year 20 days